# reading call logs in android fragments list view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i use this code for reading call logs in fragments tab activity with list view when i use the array adapter to add the values the app is unfortunately stopped but there is no run time or compile time error too 
how do i resolve it??

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment  {

    ArrayList<String> Calllist1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView callListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_call, container, false);
        callListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,Calllist1);
        callListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        getCallDetails();
        return view;
    }

    private void getCallDetails() {

        String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
        Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
        ContentResolver ca = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(callUri, null, null, null, strOrder);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            Calllist1.add(phNum);
            Calllist1.add(callTypeCode);
            Calllist1.add(strcallDate);
            Calllist1.add(callDuration);

            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            String callType;
            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;

            }

        }
        managedCursor.close();

    }

}
```

> 06-13 15:51:46.663    2998-2998/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.ndot.developer.mcp, PID: 2998
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: show your logcat..!!

Comment: how to resolve it help me

Comment: if you are using ArrayAdapter then your layout for row of listview should only contain Textview in it otherwise it will not work using ArrayAdapter

Comment: see my answer below @Tester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the Layout ID in your `onCreateView()` from `simple_list_item_2` to `simple_list_item_1`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_call, container, false);
    callListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Calllist1);
    callListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    getCallDetails();
    return view;
}
```

**Explanation :**

**Why not `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`?**

> Creating **new ArrayAdapter** need a **TextView** as a layout
>   parameter, But `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` is a
>   `TwoLineListItem` layout containing two TextViews inside it. **You
>   can check it by typing this `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`
>   string in your java file put a cursor on that and press `ctrl` key.**
>   You can see the layout.

**Why `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`?**

> `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is itself a **TextView**. Which
>   fulfills the requirement of ArrayAdapter layout being a
>   TextView. This is the reason i have suggested to use this layout.

Comment: can you tell me why it crashed and why u suggested to change simple_list_item_2 to simple_list_item_1?

Comment: @Shubham Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not passing TextviewId to adapter it crashes the app.

Replace this

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,Calllist1);
```

with

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,Calllist1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code,

```
ArrayAdapter  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Calllist1);
```